# Java applet in html without address bar

Tags: java, html

I just wanted to ask, how can we open Java Applet like a program, but not an application integrated in a web page.

You push a button in web page and java program will start, but not a java applet integrated in a web page.

Or like a webpage but without address bar :)

This is possible somehow , right?

Thank you for your time and for your answers!

**UPDATE**

This would be like a solution: http://orangoo.com/labs/greybox/normal_usage.html

Greybox!

Everything is okey, except you cant drag / move that popup window anywhere. Maybe someone is familar with Greybox and can suggest how this is possible? ( To move popup window)

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using **Java Web Start** technology instead?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/

> Java Web Start software provides the power to launch full-featured
>   applications with a single click. Users can download and launch
>   applications, such as a complete spreadsheet program or an Internet
>   chat client, without going through lengthy installation procedures.
>
> With Java Web Start software, users can launch a Java application by
>   clicking a link in a web page. The link points to a Java Network
>   Launch Protocol (JNLP) file, which instructs Java Web Start software
>   to download, cache, and run the application.

Comment: Thank you VisioN! I will try this solution :) I think this is the best idea and solution!

Comment: Mhm... By the way, is it possible to launch JNLP file without downloading it?

Comment: Nope. In fact all the elements you observe in the browser you somehow download. So it is not a big deal ;)

Comment: Yes :) but these files goes directly to "downloaded file list" :D